# Use child position to create a grid in XSLT

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, xslt

I'm trying to create a grid specified like this:

```
<Node>
  <UI>Grid</UI>
  <Rows>3</Rows>
  <Cols>3</Cols>
  <Node>stuff</Node>
  <Node>stuff</Node>
  <Node>stuff</Node>
  ...
</Node>
```

I want to use Bootstrap, so I have

```
<xsl:template match ="Node[UI[contains(., 'Grid')]]">
    <div class ="container-fluid">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Node" mode="Grid"/>
    </div>

</xsl:template>
```

And then:

```
<xsl:template match ="=Node" mode="Grid">
    <div class ="col-lg-???">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </div>

</xsl:template>
```

In the last part, col-lg-??? should somehow use the node's position as a child inside the grid node to calculate the required tag so that the grid will be properly created. Eventually, a <3,3> grid will have 9 nodes and I want to order them automatically like this:

[image: grid]

Just by using their position inside the grid node. I'm aware I would need to also consider rowing inside the container eventually, not sure about that either. `Cols` would typically be inferred 
by `Cols = Children/Rows`.

Output should be something like:

```
<div class = "container">
  <div class ="row">
    <div class = "col-lg-4" ></div>
    <div class = "col-lg-4" ></div>
    <div class = "col-lg-4" ></div>
  </div>
  <div class ="row">
    <div class = "col-lg-4" ></div>
    <div class = "col-lg-4" ></div>
    <div class = "col-lg-4" ></div>
  </div>
  <div class ="row">
    <div class = "col-lg-4" ></div>
    <div class = "col-lg-4" ></div>
    <div class = "col-lg-4" ></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

This seems to get the job done, if it were one line:

```
<div class ="col-lg-{12 div count(../Node)}">
     <xsl:apply-templates />
</div>
```

But not sure about the row part.

**EDIT2:**

What I have so far:

```
<xsl:template match ="//Sub/Node">
    <xsl:if test="count(./preceding-sibling::*) mod (count(../Node) div ../../Rows/text()) = 0">
        <div class ="row"></div>
    </xsl:if>
    <div class ="col-lg-{12 div count(../Node)}">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </div>
    <xsl:if test="count(./preceding-sibling::*) mod (count(../Node) div ../../Rows/text()) = 1">
        <div class ="rowclose"></div>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

rowclose is just for notation, it doesn't like it when I open a div in the upper if statement and close it in the second, it seems. I will try working that out. The result:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-3"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-3"></div>
    <div class="rowclose"></div>
    <div class="row"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-3"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-3"></div>
    <div class="rowclose"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What determines the `col-lg-4` in your output? Is that specific to bootstrap?

Comment: Yeah, that means that a row (which, in bootstrap, is divided to 12 cells) is divided into 3 groups of 4 cells. I actually managed to get it done using `<div class ="col-lg-{12 div count(../Node)}">`, but I'm not sure about adding the row parts.

Comment: You XSLT includes a reference to a **Sub** element in the xpath `<xsl:template match ="//Sub/Node">`, but there is no such element in the XML sample, you provide. Also, you input sample contains a lot of "stuff" but your output contains only empty elements, so it is not clear how the **Node** elements in your input correspond to the **Div** elements in your output. Perhaps showing a more complete sample would help? Thanks!

Comment: I know, sorry about that. That was just an example of the idea, I'll add the actual thing in a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% clear what it is you are trying to achieve, but I think you are trying to create three "Nodes" per row, enclosing each row in a **div** element.

If so, what you should start off by doing is selecting the **Node** elements that will be the first element in each row (where **$cols** is a variable holding the number of nodes in a row)

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="Node[position() mod $cols = 1]" mode="row"/>
```

(The "row" mode is needed here because you will end up with two templates that match **Node**)

Or if you wanted to limit the number of rows should there be more Nodes than you need, you could do this ("Position()" is context sensitive, and relates to the nodes you have just selected, not necessarily their position in the tree)

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="Node[position() mod $cols = 1][position() &lt;= $rows]" mode="row"/>
```

Then you would have a template that matches this, in "row" mode

And to select the nodes in the row, do this

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="self::*|following-sibling::Node[position() &lt; $cols]" mode="cell"/>
```

Then you would have a second template matching **Node** for the cells, where you could output the div with the class (where **lg** is a variable holding your expression to avoid it repeatedly being recalculated)

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
   <xsl:variable name="cols" select="/*/Cols" />
   <xsl:variable name="rows" select="/*/Rows" />
   <xsl:variable name="lg" select="12 div number(/*/Cols)" />

   <xsl:template match="/*">
     <div class="container">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Node[position() mod $cols = 1][position() &lt; $rows]" mode="row"/>
     </div>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Node" mode="row">
     <div class="row">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="self::*|following-sibling::Node[position() &lt;= $cols]" mode="cell"/>
     </div>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Node" mode="cell">
     <div class="col-lg-{$lg}">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
     </div>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it looks great but I'm getting a pretty fat stack of errors from Saxon Debugger...