# XSLT and misplaced HTML tags

Tags: html, xslt

I'm working on [Use child position to create a grid in XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21765452/use-child-position-to-create-a-grid-in-xslt) And my current specific problem warrants a new question, I think.

```
<xsl:template match ="//Sub/Node">
    <xsl:if test="count(./preceding-sibling::*) mod (count(../Node) div ../../Rows/text()) = 0">
        <div class ="row"></div>
    </xsl:if>
    <div class ="col-lg-{12 div count(../Node)}">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </div>
    <xsl:if test="count(./preceding-sibling::*) mod (count(../Node) div ../../Rows/text()) = 1">
        <div class ="rowclose"></div>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

I'm trying to generate a bootstrap grid from an XML description of it. The output is:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-3"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-3"></div>
    <div class="rowclose"></div>
    <div class="row"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-3"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-3"></div>
    <div class="rowclose"></div>
</div>
```

Which is close but not quite (apart from the col-lg- which have wrong numbers but are easily fixable). If I replace `<div class="row"></div>` with `<div class="row">` and `<div class="rowclose"></div>` with `</div>`, my IDE complains about misplaced tags and the page doesn't load properly.

Any way around this?

**EDIT:** I tried using `<CDATA[]]>` but then I just get the tags as strings which are printed verbatim in the output.

Comment: It would help if you could provide us with the input document that produces that XML output -- or as much of it as is relevant to that output.

Comment: What could **really** help here is if you would zoom out and provide us with **1.** the XML input you are dealing with and **2.** the output you are hoping to produce as a result of the transformation (as *code*, not as a picture). Watching your valiant efforts to produce an incorrect output does not move us closer to providing a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to make this one work with recursive templates:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="rows" select="/Node/Rows" />
    <xsl:variable name="cols" select="/Node/Cols" />
    <xsl:variable name="grid-units" select="12 div $cols" />

    <xsl:template match ="/Node">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <xsl:call-template name="make-row" />
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="make-row">
        <xsl:param name="ri" select="1"/>
        <xsl:if test="$ri &lt;= $rows">
            <div class="row">
                <xsl:call-template name="make-col">
                    <xsl:with-param name="ri" select="$ri"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </div>
            <xsl:call-template name="make-row">
                <xsl:with-param name="ri" select="$ri + 1"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="make-col">
        <xsl:param name="ci" select="1"/>
        <xsl:param name="ri"/>
        <xsl:if test="$ci &lt;= $cols">
            <div class="col-lg-{$grid-units}">
                <xsl:value-of select="Node[1 + ($ci - 1) mod $cols + $cols * ($ri - 1)]"/>
            </div>
            <xsl:call-template name="make-col">
                <xsl:with-param name="ci" select="$ci + 1"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="ri" select="$ri"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you use this as a source:

```
<Node>
    <UI>Grid</UI>
    <Rows>4</Rows>
    <Cols>2</Cols>
    <Node>One</Node>
    <Node>Two</Node>
    <Node>Three</Node>
    <Node>Four</Node>
    <Node>Five</Node>
    <Node>Six</Node>
    <Node>Seven</Node>
    <Node>Eight</Node>
    <Node>Nine</Node>
</Node>
```

you will get this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">One</div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">Two</div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">Three</div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">Four</div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">Five</div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">Six</div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">Seven</div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">Eight</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

If you change the values of `<Rows>` and `<Cols>` in the source it will distribute the `Node` fields until they are empty, placing them in the correct column or row.

Comment: Solved my problem and taught me a thing or two :)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't made XSLT for a while but if I know I already had the same problem, and I think that was due to the syntax. It's the same rule in HTML :
If you open a tag inside your parent, you can't close parent tag before the child one.

In XSL you use the xsl:if tag and then you write the div tag. You want to close your xsl:if tag before your div.

Try to change a little bit your code to check this.

If I read your code, I see that you want to close it later, but XSL parser doesn't proceed like this.

Comment: Yeah, but this isn't HTML, it's XSL. I was hoping there is a way to make it treat anything not xsl: as text.